# What is the source and destination in the following scp command?

Tags: linux, data-transfer

I am trying to copy a file from one Linux system to another Linux system. Am I correct in my attempt with `scp`? What are source and destination in this command

```
scp -r ~/setup ashok@192.168.5.223: ~/
```

?

Comment: `~/setup` is the source, `ashok@192.168.5.223: ~/` is the target (that is, `~/` on the remote host)

Comment: On UNIX like systems any command comes with a manual page. Please read it!

Comment: I +1'd the question because it is useful in my case. On CentOS 7, the manpage for scp does not say which argument is the source and which is the destination. It says the following, instead:
`...not typing the entire thing... [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2`

It looks like the one here, but without the (what I'm seeing) bunch of extra whitespace: https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

It's kind of important to know which is the source and which is the destination, especially when the program overwrites existing files...

Answer (score 3):

Basic Syntax

```
scp source_file_name username@destination_host:destination_folder
```

In your case

```
~/setup : is the source [~ : root directory and setup is a folder which you want to copy to a destination]

ashok@192.168.5.223: is the destination 
~/: location in a destination [in this case which is a root directory]
```

To understand more hit below link

http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php

Answer (score 0):

This questions suits better in [unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Here, a file named setup in your `home` directory (in the machine you're executing this command on) is the source and `home` directory on machine ashok@192.168.5.223 is the destination. It's a command to copy, it won't `move` (you'll retain the original copy), so if that's what you want, then you're right with `scp` command.

Comment: but when i execute this query from ashok@192.168.5.223 home directory copied to my home directory

Comment: @user7750849 See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html and https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp. The first thing you should have done is execute `man scp` or `scp help`.

Comment: @0xc0de:  As Pulseczar points out in a comment on the question, the man page does not say which of host1 or host2 is the source or destination.